# YQL to get Key Stats Stopped working

Tags: yahoo-finance

I have an app that uses the following url to get key stats.

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.keystats where symbol = "CSCO" | sort(field="undefined", descending="false")&env=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cynwoody/yql-tables/finance-1/tables.env&format=json&callback=?
```

It stopped working when yahoo finance user interface was changed couple of weeks ago.  Note the app was working fine before.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify: what did it used to do, what does it do now instead, what error messages or other mistaken output do you see instead?

Comment: There is no error msg.  I get a response with the symbol only.